# Changing a text file and making a bigger text file in python

Tags: python

I have a tab separated text file like these example:

`infile`:

```
chr1    +   1071396 1271396 LOC
chr12   +   1101483 1121483 MIR200B
```

I want to divide the difference between columns 3 and 4 in `infile` into 100 and make 100 rows per row in `infile` and make a new file named newfile
and make the final tab separated file with 6 columns. The first 5 columns would be like `infile`, the 6th column would be (5th column)_part number (`number` is 1 to 100).

This is the expected output file:

`expected output`:

```
chr1    +   1071396 1073396 LOC LOC_part1
chr1    +   1073396 1075396 LOC LOC_part2
.
.
.
chr1    +   1269396 1271396 LOC LOC_part100
chr12   +   1101483 1101683 MIR200B MIR200B_part1
chr12   +   1101683 1101883 MIR200B MIR200B_part2
.
.
.
chr12   +   1121283 1121483 MIR200B MIR200B_part100
```

I wrote the following code to get the expected output but it does not return what I expect.

```
file = open('infile.txt', 'rb')
cont = []
for line in file:
    cont.append(line)


newfile = []
for i in cont:
    percent = (i[3]-i[2])/100
    for j in percent:
        newfile.append(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[2]+percent, i[4], i[4]_'part'percent[j])


with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in newfile:
        for j in i:
            f.write(i + '\n')
```

Do you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: With `i[0]` or `i[1]` or whatever, you're getting characters of the line. Look into the `csv` module.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
file = open('infile.txt', 'rb')
cont = []
for line in file:
    cont.append(list(filter(lambda x: not x.isspace(), line.split(' ')))


newfile = []
for i in cont:
    diff= (int(i[3])-int(i[2]))/100 
    left = i[2] 
    right = i[2] + diff
    for j in range(100):
        newfile.append(i[0], i[1], left, right, i[4], i[4]_'part' + j)
        left = right
        right = right + diff



with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in newfile:
        for j in i:
            f.write(i + '\n')
```

In your code `for i in cont` youre loop over the string and i is a char and not string.

To fix that i split the line and remove spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

when you open the file, open it as a text file, not a binary file.

```
open('infile.txt','r')
```

now, when you read it line by line, you should strip the newline character at the end by using strip(). Then, you need to split your input text line by tabs into a list of strings, vs a just a long string containing your line, by using split('\t'):

```
line.strip().split('\t')
```

now you have:

```
file = open('infile.txt', 'r')
cont = []
for line in file:
    cont.append(line.strip().split('\t))
```

now `cont` is a list of lists, where each list contains your tab separated data. i.e.

```
cont[1][0] = 'chr12'.
```

You will probably able to take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered your question with respect to your own code, I thought I would leave my attempt at solving your problem here.

```
import os
directory = "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/"
filename = "infile.txt"
path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

with open(path, "r") as f_in, open(directory+"outfile.txt", "w") as f_out: #open input and output files
    for line in f_in:
        contents = line.rstrip().split("\t") #split line into words stored as a string 'contents'
        diff = (int(contents[3]) - int(contents[2]))/100
        for i in range(100):
            temp = (f"{contents[0]}\t+\t{int(int(contents[2])+ diff*i)}\t{contents[3]}\t{contents[4]}\t{contents[4]}_part{i+1}")
            f_out.write(temp+"\n")
```

This code doesn't follow python style convention well (excessively long lines, for example) but it works. The line `temp = ...` uses fstrings to format the output string conveniently, which you could read more about [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).